# How to set initial database file size and filegrowth in a database project?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to set the initial database file size and its auto growth parameter in a *Database Project* in *Visual Studio* to be used with the *Publish* option. I've added a *Filegroup file* (*SqlFile1.sql*) to the project with the following contents:

```sql
ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
    ADD FILE
    (
        NAME = [SqlFile1],
        FILENAME = '$(DefaultDataPath)$(DefaultFilePrefix)_SqlFile1.ndf',
        SIZE = 5000MB,
        MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED,
        FILEGROWTH = 50%
    ) TO FILEGROUP [PRIMARY]
```

([documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522469.aspx)).

When I click *Publish* with the option *Always re-create database* checked, the file `SqlFile1` is created within the *PRIMARY* filegroup, but has the *Initial size* set to *3 MB* and *Autogrowth* is *By 1 MB, unrestricted growth*. There are no error or warning messages.

What's interesting, the following SQL script:

```
ALTER DATABASE DatabaseTest
MODIFY FILE (NAME = [SqlFile1], SIZE = 5000MB, FILEGROWTH = 50%);
GO
```

ran from *SQL Management Studio* correctly modifies file's properties.

Why are my settings ignored and how to make them work?

Comment: As an F.Y.I you should never grow files by a percentage but rather choose a size in KB/MB/GB and grow in chunks of that.

Comment: @Pixelated In this task, I was dealing with generated data samples. Their number was theoretically limited for the worst-case scenario, but before that, grew exponentially. So perhaps your advice is valid in general, but for my specific task I think that percentage was the way to go (although TBH I didn't check whether it makes a difference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scripts created in the *bin* directory suggest that properties other than logical file name, physical file name and target file group are indeed ignored. Eventually I solved this issue by adding a post-deployment script. To do this right click the database project and choose *Add* -> *New item* -> *User scripts* -> *Post-Deployment Script*. In this script you can modify the database anyway you want, in this case alter file's properties with:

```
ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
    MODIFY FILE
    (
        NAME = [SqlFile1],
        SIZE = 5000MB,
        MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED,
        FILEGROWTH = 50%
    )
```

Comment: This is a workaround - even though it is perfectly acceptable, if a more direct solution exists I'll accept it (and unaccept my answer).

Answer (score 2):

The correct size and filegrowth settings can be set by creating a Filegroup file object the way you've been trying, but the key is that you *also* need to set an advanced publish setting of `Script file size` to true.

[image]

Now there's another gotcha to this, in that if you publish/create the database first *without* this option checked, then subsequent publish operations will not correctly apply the file size settings even if you've since checked this option. This is likely because the object has already been created, though I don't see why the dacfx libraries couldn't perform a similar diff to the way they do on tables. At this point you'd need to either manually change the file settings or add a post deployment script as you've mentioned here.

For reference here is a comparison to show the difference in initial create database operations with and without the Script file size option.

Without `Script file size`
[image]

With `Script file size`
[image]

With the option checked you can see the correct file size options are applied to the database deployment without the requirement of a post deployment modify db script
[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to this post of a user who had the same issue, these setting are [apparently missing in database projects](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/601532/add-database-size-and-auto-growth-settings-to-visual-studio-database-projects):

> only some database properties are available in VS database projects. In particular size and autogrowth settings are missing.

This [blog](http://phil-austin.blogspot.co.uk/2010/08/data-dude-erroring-on-deployment-over.html) however does suggest you can work around it by editing values in the `.sql` files directly (not via the IDE):

> You can change filegrowth (and other) settings of the database project, however these aren't available through the VS 2010 IDE. Instead you have to edit .sql files found here:
>
> [Project location][Database project name]\Schema
> Objects\Storage\Files

Comment: Thanks for your time. This solution seems to fit VS2010, but in my case (VS2012) I'm already editing the .sql file directly. I can of course edit it through notepad, not through VS, but it doesn't change anything. Also, I don't have the "[Project location][Database project name]\Schema Objects\Storage\Files" path - only "[Project location][Database project name]\dbo" which contains the `SqlFile1.sql` file, which I quoted in my question. And finally - I'm not receiving any errors - all goes smoothly, just these two options seem to be ignored.

Comment: @BartoszKP sorry missed that